# Click Button - No Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am trying to retrieve information from database. User enters id of the person he is looking for to ID textbox, than press display button. The grid view should show the result. But when button is pressed, nothing happens. Could anyone help or tell me what I should check?
Code for button:

```
protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="Name";Initial Catalog="Name";Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("displayData", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grvResults.DataSource = rd;
            grvResults.DataBind();
        }
```

Here is stored procedure:

```
USE ["Name"]
GO  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[displayData] (@ID int)
as
begin
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = @ID
end
```

Here is display data method:

```
public List<Customer> displayData()
        {
            List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="Name";Initial Catalog="Name";Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Customers", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                lst.Add(new Customer()
                {
                    ID = rd.GetInt32(0),
                    FName = rd.GetString(1),
                    LName = rd.GetString(2)

                });
            }
            return lst;
        }
```

aspx for button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDisplay" runat="server" Text="Display" OnClick="btnDisplay_Click" />
```

Comment: Can u also show ASPX markup for the button?

Comment: Unless I am missing something - it looks OK. Are u getting any errors? If not, are u sure SP returns data? Can u try running it by itself from SSMS with the same parameter?

Comment: I am not getting any erros, it just does not do anything. Just did and SP works good...

Comment: Can u trace in SQL Profiler if SP is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to put a breakpoint in button click. Is it hitting breakpoint. If not then I will say remove

```
OnClick="btnDisplay_Click"
```

from your aspx page. And then add default click event from .cs page by selecting control and it events. Them try to debug line by line.

Comment: I checked the onclick event and i seems like i had VS bug. When i rewrote everything again, it started to work

Answer (score 0):

Give the following code a try in your codebehind. It should bind properly and fill a gridview. If it works, add more code from there. If it doesn't work, look at things like your connection string. Let me know.

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="?";Initial Catalog="?";Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = @ID", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

        grvResults.DataSource = dt;
        grvResults.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why? grid can bind to DataReader as well as DataTable.

Comment: I'm not really sure what he is trying to accomplish. He used `conn.Open()` twice in his code, and never calls `conn.Close()` I just wanted to provide code that works, I doubt performance between datatables and datareaders is a consideration at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating yourself too much
First do this:
[image: Select the first option: SQL statement or stored procedure]
[image: Then select your stored procedure]
[image: Select The source Control (your Textbox) then click next]

[image: Then enter your client Id and click the button. NOTE on the button click you need to write this: **SqlDataSource1.DataBind();**]

That should make it work. You already have a stored procedure which makes it easier. (Sorry for the pictures, I wanted to make sure you understood this)

Comment: Thanks, yes it works and i tried it before. I just whant to do it other way.